# COM/ActiveX and Downloading url

Tags: c++, internet-explorer, plugins, com, activex

I am have an ActiveX that asks a server for a URL and downloads / reads the data and ask for a new buffer of data until completion. The data gets read correctly, but if I watch the task manager the memory and the handles for IE go up and never come down. Process explorer shows that the handles are to the cache files.

```
int AXGetUrl(char*     url,
             void*     buffer,   
             int       buffer_size,
             void*     pUnk)
{
char                    buffer2[256];
int                     rc;
HRESULT                 rc2;
ULONG                   buffer_len;
ULONG                   buffer_len2;
IStream*                pStream;
char                    newurl[1024];
ULONG64                 RequestBytes;
CURLCallBack            UCB;

    //Initialize
    rc = 0;
    rc2 = 0;
    memset(newurl,
           0x00,
           sizeof(newurl));
    buffer_len = 0;
    pStream = NULL;
    RequestBytes = 0;
    strcpy(newurl,
           url);

    rc = URLOpenBlockingStream((IUnknown *)pUnk,
                               url,
                               &pStream,
                               0,
                               &UCB);    
    while (rc == 0)
        {
        if  (pStream != NULL)
            {
            rc2 = pStream->Read(buffer,
                                buffer_size,
                                &buffer_len);
            RequestBytes = RequestBytes + buffer_len;

            pStream->Release();        
            pStream = NULL;

            buildnewurl(newurl,
                        RequestBytes);
            rc = URLOpenBlockingStream((IUnknown *)pUnk,
                                       newurl,
                                       &pStream,
                                       0,
                                       &UCB);
            }
        else
            {
            rc = 1;
            }
        }

    return (rc);
}
```

UPDATE:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Test.h"

Test::Test()
{
}
Test::~Test()
{
}

HRESULT Test::FinalConstruct()
{
void*       pUnk = NULL;
void*       buffer = NULL;
int         buffer_size = 131072;
ULONG       buffer_len = 0;
HRESULT     rc = 0;
HRESULT     rc2 = 0;
IStream*    pStream = NULL;
int         counter = 0;
char        url[1024];

    rc = QueryInterface(IID_IUnknown, &pUnk);
    buffer = malloc(buffer_size);
    if  (buffer != NULL)
        {
        //Get URL
        sprintf(url,
                "http://search.yahoo.com/search?p=%d",
                counter);
        rc = URLOpenBlockingStream((IUnknown *)pUnk,
                                    url,
                                    &pStream,
                                    0,
                                    NULL);    
        while (rc == 0)
            {
            if  (pStream != NULL)
                {
                rc2 = pStream->Read(buffer,
                                    buffer_size,
                                    &buffer_len);
                pStream->Release();        
                pStream = NULL;

                counter++;
                if (counter == 15)
                    {
                    break;
                    }
                sprintf(url,
                        "http://search.yahoo.com/search?p=%d",
                        counter);
                rc = URLOpenBlockingStream((IUnknown *)pUnk,
                                           url,
                                           &pStream,
                                           0,
                                           NULL);
                }
            else
                {
                rc = 1;
                }
            }
        free(buffer);
        }

    return (S_OK);
}

void Test::FinalRelease()
{
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are making a call to 'URLOpenBlockingStream' to retrieve a stream object but the stream it returns is never deleted. Assuming that `IStream` is a COM object you need to call `Release()` once you are done with `pStream`...

```
rc = URLOpenBlockingStream((IUnknown *)pUnk,
                           url,
                           &pStream,
                           0,
                           &UCB);
while (rc == 0)
{
    // ... your code here...
}

if(pStream != NULL)
{
    pStream->Release();
}
```

Comment: Correct and I do have a ->Relase() being called.  Modified my code above to take out one of the Read() and still get the open handles to the cache file. After each successful read (where all the data is read) I need to ask for another new URL.

Comment: Then the problem exists beyond the code you have posted. You will need to either post code that is more relevant to the problem or dig in with a debugger.

Comment: Here is the all of my C code at the smallest I could make it and provide a realistic example of the issue. If you think the H, rc, or idl files are necessary I can add them. If there is anything I am missing let me know.